# RRule.js online too dtstart format

Tags: rrule

It is not clear to me what is the format of the date to be filled in the dtstart form field.
[RRule JS online tool](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/)

I have tried a few things and the output generates always "

> => Error: Invalid options: dtstart "

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome , it becomes obvious what the format is.
The autocompletion on field does not work on firefox.

http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/